# Не могу разархивировать .vmdk

Tags: vmware

Хочу установить mac os x sierra нa windows 7 vmware, скачал файл на .rar, и при разархивации выдает ошибку `the file is corrupted`. Ни как не могу разархивировать файл, чтобы запустить на VM.

Comment: А где тут вопрос?

Comment: Kak mojno razarxivirovat etot file?

Comment: Если у вас файл скачан не полностью или с ошибкой - заново скачать.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш файл поломан. Скачайте заново.

Comment: Skachal 10 raz iz drugix istochnikov to je problema